# Jenkins: Nexus Repository Manager 2.x connection succeeded but showing 0 hosted release Maven 2 repositories

Tags: jenkins, nexus

I having a hard time figuring out an issue described as below;

I have Jenkins 2.121.2 and Nexus 2.14 installed on a production server which is Linux Redhat system. I have a maven project and my task is to deploy the project artifact in the nexus hosted repository.

I have installed the Nexus Platform Plugin and configured in jenkins the requisite.
After the configuration it is showing connection succeeded but it is not able to identify any maven2 release repositiories

[image: Jenkins Screenshot]

[image: Nexus Screenshot]

I have the same setup in my local windows laptop and it is a able to detect the hosted release repositories. But in the linux red hat environment it is causing the issue. Any help highly appreciated.